# pyinstaller not loading any dependencies

Tags: python, import, dependencies, executable, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller for the first time. I used examples from youtube and stackoverflow too see if I would replicate the same results. However in my case it might seem that pyinstaller does not load the dependencies. For example I have the code:

```
import time, request

def main():
   print('hello world!')
   time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

In the original example the person running it did not have to create hooks or anything extra. But I get ImportError: No module named request. Which makes me think something is wrong with my pyinstaller. It is version 3.3.1 and I am using python 2.7. It should be correct according to the documentation of pyinstaller.
However it is not working :( Any help is really appreciated! :)

Comment: Why are you importing the request module? There is no standard module in python 2.7 named "request". Do you want to use the 'requests' (mind the 's') module? If so, you need to install it first: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Thank you for that catch!:D it works now. So, the original program that I wanted to make into an executable with pyinstaller was importing load_workbook from openpyxl. Since i got import error I took a step back, and tried to make this simple program work first. Now I am just adding import openpyxl next to requests and it again will not work... Do you have any insight into this ? Appreciate it ! :)

Comment: It is working now! I installed openpyxl. On the first run it didnt but i moved the import one line below and now it works, strangely enough! But I am not complaining!

Comment: I think it was because the script was changed, the executable had to be built again

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed the `requests`

Run 
`pip install requests`
in terminal to install it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using Pycharm and I installed it already in he project interpreter, and it runs fine. Shouldnt pyinstaller take care of dependencies? The pyinstaller logging doesnt even look for it, as far as I can see. I tried your suggestion too, but it still does not work for me :(